# How can I get the HTML5 calendar date input to show the popup?

Tags: html

I wrote the following:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="date" />
</body>
</html>
```

Just something basic so I could see it working. It rendered a textbox on the page but when I click it no date pop up shows. I tried in both IE9 and Chrome.

Is there something else you need to do to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, according to [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime), neither the date or time input type is supported in IE9 (support for IE10 is unknown).

The only major browser that currently supports the date input type is Opera and Opera Mobile.

Now, whenever the major browsers detect an unknown input type they default to `type="text"` so there is no harm in leaving the type field as date for future users. If you want to implement the calendar functionality now and not rely on browser support, your best bet is to look into cross-browser compatible JavaScript plugins. If you use jQuery, there are probably a dozen or more major plugins available that you could freely use.